# How can I create dynamic array without asking user to enter a size in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-arrays, login-system

I want to take 8 char password from user and then when she/he wanted to enter, I wanted it to be whatever size she/he enter. However, the code doesn't stop until it reaches 8 char, even I press 'enter', it takes it as a char and create '*'. I want its size to be whatever user write and then user press 'enter', it will take these characters as password to see if it is matched with registered password. For example;

- User register password as 'wellcode'
- After that, user write in login screen 'well' then enter(in my code it lasts until I reach 8 characte
- 'Login failed! will be written

Is there a way to do that in C++?

```
    bool CheckCredentials(string);
       char pass[8], inPass[8];
       int main()
        {
            fstream encrypted;
            bool done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                cout << "1. Register a password" << endl;
                cout << "2. Login your password" << endl;
                cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
                
                int menuChoice;
                cin >> menuChoice;
        
                if (menuChoice == 1)
                {
                    
                    ifstream ifile;
                    ifile.open("password.txt");
                    if (ifile){}
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "New password must contain only 8 characters: ";
                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                            pass[i] = _getch(); _putch('*');
                        }
                        ofstream l("password.txt", ios::out);
                        if (!l.is_open()) {
                            cout << "could not open file \n";
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                            l << pass[i];
                        }
                        l.close();
                        cout << "\n\n";
                    }
                }
        
                else if (menuChoice == 2)
                {
        
                        cout << "Password: ";
                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                            inPass[i] = _getch(); _putch('*');
                        }
        
        
                        if (CheckCredentials(inPass) == true)
                        {
                            cout << "\nLogin sucessful!" << "\n\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "\nLogin failed!"
                        }
        
                }
                else if (menuChoice == 3)
                {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        
            return 0;
        }

bool CheckCredentials(string inPass)
{
    string s;

    bool status = false;

    ifstream f;
    f.open("password.txt");

    if (!f.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
    }
    else if (f)
    {
        while (!f.eof())
        {
            f >> s;

            if (inPass == s)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }

    f.close();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) exists. So does [`<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and, if you really *really* need the utmost performance, [`<array>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). There is really no reason to use C arrays in C++, other than interfacing with C code.

Comment: *Is there a way to do that in C++?* -- C++ is used to create game engines, operating systems, control equipment, computer-aided design, robotics, and many, if most of your favorite applications. So the obvious answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: The length of the password should be irrelevant and you shouldn't even pass it around. Best to hash it directly after input and only ever pass the hash around. The shorter you have the password in memory the less likely someone manages to steal it. You could even feed the keystrokes directly into hashing code so the password is never stored in memory at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    inPass[i] = _getch();
    _putch('*');
}
```

Obviously that loops exactly eight times, doesn't matter what you type.

If you want to stop the loop early then you must write the code to test for that possibility. Something like

```
int inPassLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
     char ch = _getch(); 
     if (ch == '\n')  // quit loop if enter is pressed
         break;
     inPass[inPassLength++] = ch; 
     putch('*'); 
}
```

You also need to add a variable to record how long the password is (since it may not be exactly 8 characters any more) that's what `inPassLength` is in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` runs *exactly* eight times so you read *exactly* eight characters.

Instead you need to discover the user completing the password by pressing *enter* key and break the loop in that case. Additionally you need to consider the real number of characters the user entered, not again iterate *exactly* eight times to output the characters.

Then you haven't considered at all the user deleting input again! It would be pretty unhandy to see additional asterisks appear on pressing backspace key!

To cover all this I recommend using `std::string` instead and iterate endlessly, such as follows:

```
std::string pw;
for(;;)
{
    char c = getch();
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
    if(c == '\b')
    {
        putch('\b'); // remove character from screen
        pw.resize(pw.length() - 1); // remove character from storage
    }
    else
    {
        putch('*');
        pw += c;
    }
}
if(pw.length() > 8)
{
    // too long!
}
else
{
    std::ofstream l /*...*/;

    l << pw; // just output the entire string at once...
}
```

Note: This is entirely untested code! If you find a bug, please fix yourself.

Note, too, that this answer does not cover *every* potential user behaviour (pressing backspace is just the most prominent one), e.g. pressing the arrow keys to move the cursor, `del` button (even at input end), ... To cover some of these you might fall back to even more low level API ([`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) and similar).